# Bulk load in hazelcast map using ttl based on map entry

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I need to load around 10 millions records from flat file in hazelcast map.Also the ttl needs to set based on each map entry.
What is most efficient way to do the same?

Currently i am using Imap.putall().Is there a way to set ttl based on map entry using putall?

Comment: What version of Hazelcast ? How many members ? Simple iterating with `IMap.put(K,V,TTL)` isn't going to be great but might be fast enough. Jet might be an option also, if there are sufficient members to make a difference.

Comment: I am using hazelcast 3.12 version. 5 members per cluster.Total 3 clusters.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an API that allows you to do bulk put with individual expiry.

The code below would be a way to do it with Hazelcast Jet writing into Hazelcast's IMap.

The client submits this job and the grid servers process, reading a single file of input server side. The line `.groupingKey` partitions the input stream by
the entry key, so each server does a `map.put` where the key will be local, but enriched with a different TTL for each entry.

This is an alternative to iterating across your input file and insert each key individually. Whether it is faster will depend on factors such as the network speed, number of servers, and so on. It is certainly more complicated than simple iteration, so the speed gain would need to justify the complexity.

```
public class MyClient implements EntryExpiredListener<Long, Long> {

    private static final String INPUT_DIRECTORY = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/input_data";
    private static final String MAP_NAME = "test";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyClient().go();
    }
    
    public void go() {
        JetInstance jetInstance = Jet.newJetClient();
        
        jetInstance.getMap(MAP_NAME).addEntryListener(this, false);
        
        Pipeline pipeline = MyClient.buildPipeline();
        
        JobConfig jobConfig = new JobConfig();
        jobConfig.addClass(MyClient.class);
        
        try {
            jetInstance.newJob(pipeline, jobConfig).join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process a file that looks like <pre>
     * % cat test/input
     * 1
     * 2
     * 3
     * 4
     * 5
     * </pre>
     * @return
     */
    private static Pipeline buildPipeline() {
        ComparatorEx<Tuple3<Long, Long, Long>> comparatorEx = ComparatorEx.comparingLong(Tuple3::f0);

        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create();

        BatchStage<String> input = pipeline.readFrom(MyClient.mySource(INPUT_DIRECTORY));
        
        // Convert to trios of key, value, expiry
        BatchStage<Tuple3<Long, Long, Long>> tuples
            = input
                .map(line -> {
                    long l = Long.parseLong(line);
                    return Tuple3.<Long, Long, Long>tuple3(100 * l, 200 * l, 300 * l);
                });
        
        // Route per JVM based on entry key
        BatchStage<Entry<Long, Tuple3<Long, Long, Long>>> routedEntries
            = tuples
                .groupingKey(Tuple3::f0)
                .rollingAggregate(AggregateOperations.maxBy(comparatorEx));
        
        // Custom map save using expiry
        routedEntries.writeTo(MyClient.mySink(MAP_NAME));
        
        // [Optional] all log entries to systout
        routedEntries.writeTo(Sinks.logger());
                
        return pipeline;
    }

    private static BatchSource<String> mySource(String directory) {
        return Sources.filesBuilder(directory)
                .sharedFileSystem(true)
                .build();
    }

    private static Sink<? super Entry<Long, Tuple3<Long, Long, Long>>> mySink(String mapName) {
            return SinkBuilder.sinkBuilder("mySink", 
                    processorContext -> processorContext.jetInstance().<Long, Long>getMap(mapName))
                .receiveFn((IMap<Long, Long> map, Entry<Long, Tuple3<Long, Long, Long>> entry) -> {
                    map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().f1(), entry.getValue().f2(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void entryExpired(EntryEvent<Long, Long> entryEvent) {
        System.out.println(entryEvent.getEventType() + " for " + entryEvent.getKey());
    }

}
```